# Can't authorize with Dropbox Java SDK

Tags: java, dropbox, dropbox-api

I started developing some Dropbox app. I stucked on authorization.
Here's my code:

```
package ubox.model;

import com.dropbox.core.*;

import java.util.Locale;


public class DXauth 
{
    private DbxWebAuthNoRedirect webAuth; 

    public void auth() //throws IOException, DbxException
    {
        final String APP_KEY = "foo";
        final String APP_SECRET = "foo";

        DbxAppInfo appInfo = new DbxAppInfo(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);

        DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig("JavaTutorial/1.0", Locale.getDefault().toString());

        webAuth = new DbxWebAuthNoRedirect(config, appInfo);

    }



    public String getAuthorizeUrl()
    {
        return webAuth.start();
    }

}
```

I'm getting such error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParseException
    at com.dropbox.core.DbxAppInfo.<clinit>(DbxAppInfo.java:112)
    at ubox.model.DXauth.auth(DXauth.java:17)
    at Main.main(Main.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 3 more
```

I have included jars to build path from dropbox. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: The error seems to indicate that a necessary library, specifically the Jackson-core library, wasn't found. It's included as lib/jackson-core-2.2.4.jar with the Dropbox Core Java SDK. You mentioned you included it though, so can you elaborate on how you did so? What IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using Eclipse IDE. I just clicked right mouse button on my project in Project Explorer. Then I chose Build Path > Configure Build Path. Then in Libraries tab I clicked add external jars.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Normally I just add the jars to the libs folder, but I believe your method should work too. I actually just tried it and it did work for me, so it sounds like something may be broken in your environment. I would recommend trying it again in case something got disconnected.

Comment: Today I have tried "lib directory" method. The same error occurs.